# HTML customize a button of the type file

Tags: html, css

I have this button

[image]

Here is the code of this button

`<input type="file" value="Upload" id="fileToUpload">`

My question: Can i customize this button? Change the text inside the button to "Upload" and not "Durchsuchen...". And if i choosed a file, is on the right side the name of the file, i dont like it. Can i remove the name?

Comment: the `value` is what determine the name the button is displaying. You can customize the rest with CSS

Comment: If i change the value, nothing happens. Can i remove the name on the right side with css too?

Comment: Can you post some code please? Then I'll tell you

Comment: Here is a fiddle of the form [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhzvx87m/)